# Is there a way to run curl in RSelenium browser?

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, rselenium

I need to scrape a website with dynamic data loading (i.e. "read more") capabilities and content reachable only by curl parsing. Is it possible to render the website with `RSelenium` (or a similar package) then parse with `curl` package instead of `getPageSource` command?

Comment: Why can't you use RSelenium to dynamically load the data and then pull it down with getPageSource? Can you provide the actual site address and the data you want to scrape?

Comment: With curl, somehow I can get tooltip data information as embedded json in span tags. getPageSource gives you only html source but not the json responses. I can't give you the url but I will try to find a MWE.